# Grab JVM execution status from bash script

Tags: java, bash, logging

I have a **bash** script which starts a **JVM** in the background and then exits. But, many times JVM fails with exceptions. How do I get final execution status, i.e., **success/failure/errors, in the bash** before I exit the bash shell?

Comment: Maybe you should run your Java process as a systemd service: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-java-jar-application-with-systemd-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

JVM is not different from any other process, on failure it returns a non-zero exit code. Script should just pay attention to the exit code. To force it do so add `set -e` to the beginning of the script, it will start failing on the first failure and simplify the debugging.

Normally, all your production scripts would start with the below combo

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
```

And one of many ways to not ignore the exit code of the child process would be

```
java -cp ... || { echo "child failed" >&2; exit 1; }
```